# Android R.id error

Tags: android

I have the following code and have an error in action_settings in R.id.action_settings. This is in the last method posted here so scroll down. I am not sure what is supposed to go in here. I am trying to create an app that has a login page at the start, with the potential to create a new user id in a registration page, take a picture in another page, and see a menu in another page.

```
package com.example.reynaldo.project1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onButtonClick (View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin) {
        EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFemail);
        String str = a.getText().toString();
        EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpassword);
        String pass = b.getText().toString();

        String password = helper.searchPass(str);

        if (pass.equals(password)) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
            i.putExtra("Email", str);
            startActivity(i);

        } else {
            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username and password don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            temp.show();
        }
    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bsignup){
        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings){
        return true;
    }
    return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Can you share your logcat?

Comment: it just says "cannot resolve symbol "action_settings". I have no file or object named like that. I am not sure what it is supposed to be?

Comment: check if there is any problem with resource I guess your `R` file is not generated. Check your **logcat**.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to import R.

```
import youPackage.R;
```

This way you can manually import R.

Please replace yourPackage with your package name of application. You can find it in your Manifest.xml file or with build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.example.reynaldo.project1.R
```

in your file and check you have a menu item with id action_settings and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `R.menu.main` xml file does not contain an item having `@+id/action_settings` as its id. Check your R.menu.main xml file and make sure the action_settings id is set

Answer (score 0):

import yourpackagename.R;

For Ex:

```
import com.example.reynaldo.project1.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your menu file and make sure you have created item with 
 id = action_settings